# What is the best data structure and algorithm in this situation?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have a program that is just one big for loop. I first have an empty set. On each iteration of the for loop I need to peek and remove the minimum value from the set. Also in each iteration I can add anywhere from 0 to 8 values to the set(values are random). Which built in Java data structure should I use? I considered doing a bubble sort with an ArrayList and just taking out the first index. I'm am looking for the the fastest algorithm to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [PriorityQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html). It provides O(log(n)) time for the insertion methods (`add()`, `remove()`); constant time for the retrieval methods(`size()`, `peek()`).

Comment: You could mention that deletion is also O(log(n)).

Comment: Actually you have a few too many "and"s now, including a very functional-looking `and()` :-P

Comment: @j_random_hacker, Please could you explain me why?

Comment: What is `and()` doing in sentence #2?